# How do I show a message box with Qt Quick Controls?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

What is the equivalent of `QMessageBox::information()` when one wishes to write a QML application using Qt Quick Controls?

Comment: In my project I use a QML window component as a modal for this that I tailored to my needs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick-window2-window.html

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Qt 6.3 and later you can use [MessageDialog](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html#details) from `QtQuick.Dialogs`:

```
MessageDialog {
    text: "The document has been modified."
    informativeText: "Do you want to save your changes?"
    buttons: MessageDialog.Ok | MessageDialog.Cancel

    onAccepted: Qt.quit()
}
```

In Qt 6.2 and earlier you can use [MessageDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-messagedialog.html) from `Qt.labs.platform` (using the same example code as above).

In Qt 5 you can use [MessageDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html) from `QtQuick.Dialogs 1.x`:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

MessageDialog {
    id: messageDialog
    title: "May I have your attention please"
    text: "It's so cool that you are using Qt Quick."
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("And of course you could only agree.")
        Qt.quit()
    }
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You Can use [Popup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html) In QtQuick Controls 2 :

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 // or import Qt.labs.controls 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true
Button {
    text: "Open"
    onClicked: popup.open()
}

Popup {
    id: popup
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 200
    height: 300
    modal: true
    focus: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok this does the job (badly). Import the `Window` object:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
```

Then add this to your main window (or you could put it in another file I guess):

```
function showMessage(text, title)
{
    messageBox.text = text;
    messageBox.title = title;
    messageBox.visible = true;
}

Window {
    id: messageBox
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
    title: ""
    visible: false
    property alias text: messageBoxLabel.text
    color: parent.color
    minimumHeight: 100
    minimumWidth: 300
    Label {
        anchors.margins: 10
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: messageBoxButton.top
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        id: messageBoxLabel
        text: ""
    }

    Button {
        anchors.margins: 10
        id: messageBoxButton
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text: "Ok"
        onClicked: messageBox.visible = false
    }
}
```

Problems with it:

1. The window can be shrunk so that the text and button overlap.
2. The minimum window size is hard-coded rather than calculated from the text size.
3. You can't select the text.
4. Looks a bit shit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't one, at least not in the shipping Qt Quick Controls as of Qt 5.1.1 :(

You need to add it to your project via a [`QObject` wrapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html#exposing-attributes-of-c-classes-to-qml).

Answer (score 1):

```
// CenteredDialog.qml
import QtQml 2.2

import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Dialog {
    parent: ApplicationWindow.overlay

    x: (parent.width - width) / 2
    y: (parent.height - height) / 2

    focus: true
    modal: true

    property alias text: messageText.text

    Label {
        id: messageText

        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok
}
```

You can declare `CenteredDialog { id: centeredDialog }` somewhere, then in some event handler you may call:

```
 centeredDialog.title = qsTr("Error!")
 centeredDialog.text = qsTr("Access violation")
 centeredDialog.visible = true
```