# QtQuick2 - custom MessageBox

Tags: javascript, qt, mobile, qml, messagebox

Does anyone know how to implement custom MessageBox for mobile devices? I've tried to use `Window` type, but with no luck (it just shows but somewhere out of screen). I appreciate if someone can show me why usage of `Window` doesn't work. I used also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788039/how-do-i-show-a-message-box-with-qt-quick-controls). But on mobile devices it doesn't work.

Here is my current code, using `Window`. As said, it doesn't work since it does show out of screen range.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Item{

    function showMessage(text, title)
    {
        messageBox.text = text;
        messageBox.title = title;
        messageBox.visible = true;
    }

    Window {
        id: messageBox
        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
        title: ""
        visible: false
        property alias text: messageBoxLabel.text
        color: parent.color
        minimumHeight: 100
        minimumWidth: 300
        Label {
            anchors.margins: 10
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: messageBoxButton.top
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            id: messageBoxLabel
            text: ""
        }

        Button {
            anchors.margins: 10
            id: messageBoxButton
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: "Ok"
            onClicked: messageBox.visible = false
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone show me why it's working wrong?

Comment: What OS? Where's your code?

Comment: "Does anyone know how to implement custom MessageBox for mobile devices?" - how many OSes with Qt you've seen on mobile? For this particular question I can say "Android"

Comment: Qt supports Android, iOS, WinRT/Windows Mobile, BlackBerry, Sailfish, and Tizen is WIP.

Comment: I have Android, iOS, Blackberry devices and Sailfish, Tizen simulators. If you can show me example of proper creation of custom message box for any of them (even for Windows Mobile) I'll appreciate it.

Comment: You could try switching to "MessageDialog" QML type if that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but my actual need is to try implement fully custom element with current qml primitives, as you see I've tried to do it with window but with no luck

Comment: There's the [`Dialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html) type - if you are using Qt 5.4+. Using primitives and controls you can create whichever message box you want. Differently from `MessageBox`, which uses the native Android dialog, you are in full control here. Using it and overriding the `contentItem` you can also create a fully modal message box (see [my example of an Android busy dialog](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2015-June/017173.html)

Comment: It sounds like my actual goal. Thanks, I will try to learn more about `Dialog` type

Comment: If your target is android, that IS your goal. Try my code - last link - on a device to see the outcome of such an example. As for the `Window` issue, it could be related to the fact that there's no windowing system (as traditionally intended) on Android. I remember some document recommending to avoid multiple windows on Android.

Comment: Yeah, It's looks almost ideally. Please post your answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MessageBox.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Rectangle {
    id: mainWrapper
    color: "#80000000"
    x: 0;
    y: 0;
    width: parent.width;
    height: parent.height;
    opacity: 0;
    Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.OutExpo } }
    visible: opacity > 0

    property string text;

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        preventStealing: true
    }

    signal finished(bool ok);

    function init() {
        opacity = 1;
        msgB.scale = 1.0;
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: msgB
        color: "#323232"
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0; color: "#323232" }
            GradientStop { position: 1; color: "#252525" }
        }
        //radius: 7

        width: parent.width * 0.4;
        height: cont.height + 20 * 2;
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        scale: 0.6
        Behavior on scale { NumberAnimation { duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.OutExpo } }
        Behavior on height { NumberAnimation { duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.OutExpo } }

        Column {
            id: cont
            width: parent.width;
            y: 20;
            spacing: 20;
            Text {
                color: "#ffffff"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                font {
                    bold: false;
                    pixelSize: 21;
                }
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap;
                text: mainWrapper.text;
            }
            Button {
                anchors.margins: 10
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                text: "OK"
                onClicked: {
                    mainWrapper.opacity = 0;
                    msgB.scale = 0.6;
                    mainWrapper.finished(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere in `main.qml` file (`window` is the id of `main.qml` element):

```
function message(msg, finished) {
    var alert = Qt.createComponent("MessageBox.qml").createObject(window, { text: msg });
    alert.onFinished.connect(function(ok) {
        if (ok) {
            if (finished)
                finished();
        }
        alert.destroy(500);
    });
    alert.init();
    return alert;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Button {
    ...
    onClicked: {
        message("Hello world", function() { console.log("OK clicked"); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for answers and comments, summarizing above I created element without Window type, but with contentItem property. It's very raw element, but usable like `Dialog` as suggested by [BaCaRoZzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538363/bacarozzo) or `Window` as in [Mechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007890/mechan) example.

Here is source:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true
    id: win
    color: brPalette.charcoal
    BreezeQuickMessageBox{
        id: mbox
        palette: brPalette
        contentItem: Rectangle{
            color: "lightblue"
            anchors.fill: parent
            BreezeQuickButton{
                id: btn
                anchors {
                    verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
                palette: brPalette
                gradiented: false
                onClicked: {
                    mbox.hide()
                }
            }
        }
    }
/*
Another bunch of code
*/
    BreezeQuickPalette{
        id: brPalette
        theme: "dark"
    }
}
```

**BreezeQuickMessageBox.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: root
    property BreezeQuickPalette palette: BreezeQuickPalette
    property bool __buttonGradiented: false
    property string title: "Message Box"
    property Item contentItem
    anchors.fill: parent
    Behavior on opacity {
        NumberAnimation{
            duration: 250
        }
    }
    opacity: 0
    visible: opacity > 0
    z: parent.z + 100
    BreezeQuickPalette{
        id: __palette
        theme: palette.theme
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: window
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height*0.4
        anchors {
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        z: parent.z + 1
        color: palette.charcoal
        Item {
            id: content
            width: parent.width
            anchors {
                top: titleText.bottom
                bottom: line.top
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                topMargin: 8
                bottomMargin: 8
            }
            children: contentItem
        }
        Rectangle{
            id: line
            width: parent.width
            anchors{
                bottom: buttonArea.top
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
            height: 1
            color: palette.focusColor
        }
        Text{
            id: titleText
            font.pointSize: buttonOk.font.pointSize
            color: palette.normalText
            text: title
            anchors {
                top: parent.top
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                topMargin: 16
            }
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
        Rectangle{
            id: buttonArea
            width: parent.width
            anchors{
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                bottom: window.bottom
            }
            height: buttonOk.height*1.2
            color: "transparent"
        }
        BreezeQuickButton {
            id: buttonOk
            caption: "Ok"
            width: 128
            palette: __palette
            gradiented: __buttonGradiented
            anchors{
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                verticalCenter: buttonArea.verticalCenter
            }
            onClicked: {
                root.hide()
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle{
        id: shadow
        anchors.fill: parent
        z: parent.z
        color: palette.shadeBlack
        opacity: 0.4
        MouseArea{
            id: rootArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
        }
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: palette.black }
            GradientStop { position: 0.1; color: palette.shadeBlack }
            GradientStop { position: 0.3; color: palette.grey }
            GradientStop { position: 0.7; color: palette.grey }
            GradientStop { position: 0.9; color: palette.shadeBlack }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: palette.black }
        }
    }

    function show (title, message) {
        root.opacity = 1
    }
    function hide () {
        root.opacity = 0
    }
}
```

And actual look for Android:

[image: Application mainwindow]

[image: MessageBox in action]